# Reading dataset in SAS where column length is unequal

Tags: sas

I am trying to read the following dataset. How would i be able to read it correctly as I have tried the following solution but it is unable to work.

```
data test; 
infile datalines dlm="*" dsd truncover; 
input ID Store$ Date mmddyy10. Amount Code Color$; 
datalines; 
14528*instore*06/15/2008*215.65**red
14529*online*06/15/2008*183.98*1650039*white
14530**06/16/2008*107.50*1650450*green
14531*instore*06/17/2008*350.78*1652903*graphite
; 
run;
```

Comment: The INFORMAT statement does NOT have to be before the INPUT statement.

Comment: @Tom Indeed, I edited my answer. The only difference is that with the informat before the input statement, the date column will be the first column in the dataset.

Comment: Yes, SAS will define the variables in the order that it sees them in the data step.  It will also define the type and length of the variable at the first place the variable is used where that information is required.  Both the informat and input statements are ones that will force SAS to define the type and length of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon `:` modifier to read the date. It allows you to read non-standard data values and character values that are longer than eight characters, but which have no embedded blanks.

```
data test;
    infile datalines dlm="*" dsd truncover;
    input ID Store $ Date :mmddyy10. Amount Code Color $;
    datalines;
14528*instore*06/15/2008*215.65**red
14529*online*06/15/2008*183.98*1650039*white
14530**06/16/2008*107.50*1650450*green
14531*instore*06/17/2008*350.78*1652903*graphite
;
run;

Result:
 id    store     date  amount code     color
 14528 instore   17698 215.65 .        red
 14529 online    17698 183.98 1650039  white
 14530           17699 107.5  1650450  green
 14531 instore   17700 350.78 1652903  graphite
```

As store is a character variable, the missing value will be represented as a `*blank*` whereas `.` for numerical one (code).

PS: Instead of the `:` modifier, you could also use the INFORMAT statement before or after the INPUT statement:

```
data test;
    infile datalines dlm="*" dsd truncover;
    informat date mmddyy10.;
    input ID Store$ Date Amount Code Color $;
    datalines;
14528*instore*06/15/2008*215.65**red
14529*online*06/15/2008*183.98*1650039*white
14530**06/16/2008*107.50*1650450*green
14531*instore*06/17/2008*350.78*1652903*graphite
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LIST MODE input to allow the INPUT statement to use the delimiters to determine what part of the line to read for each variable.  You are using LIST MODE for most of the variables in your INPUT statement, but you have changed to FORMATTED mode for the DATE variable because you included an INFORMAT specification in-line in the INPUT statement.

When the INPUT statement reads a variable with FORMATTED mode it reads **exactly** the number of characters requried by the informat specification.  If the length of the next string does not exactly match the number of characters required by the informat that means it might read too many characters or too few.

You can use the `:` modifier after the variable DATE to tell the INPUT statement to use the informat specification included in the INPUT statement, but still parse the line using LIST MODE.  Note that when reading the variable with LIST MODE the width of the informat specification is ignored for reading.  Instead the INPUT statement will read **all** of the characters in the next "word" whatever its width.

```
input ID Store $ Date :mmddyy. Amount Code Color $;
```

You can also attach an informat to the variable DATE using the INFORMAT statement and remove the informat specification from the INPUT statement.  It does not matter whether the INFORMAT statement is before or after the INPUT statement as the INFORMAT statement is a non-executable statement.

```
input ID Store $ Date Amount Code Color $;  
informat date mmddyy.;
format date date9.;
```